# Doctest failed with zero exit code

Tags: python, doctest

In my test code, my doctest fails but the script exits with a zero return value, which causes the CI run to pass, which is not intended.

Is this the correct behavior of doctest module?

My script ends with:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

The output is like:

```
**********************************************************************
File "test/test.py", line 7, in __main__
Failed example:
    f(1,0)
Expected:
    -----
    type: <type 'exceptions.ZeroDivisionError'>
    value: integer division or modulo by zero
    x
    -----
Got:
    -----
    type: <type 'exceptions.ZeroDivisionError'>
    value: integer division or modulo by zero
    -----
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
   1 of   1 in __main__
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
tux@iPad:~/programming/exception-notifier(fix-travis)(0)$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: Can you please post the full stacktrace ?

Comment: dropping the X from your docstring ?

Comment: That x is deliberately added to make the test fail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find using `doctest.testmod(raise_on_error=True)` will cause an exception to be raised when a test fails, which causes the script exits with a non-zero code.

[Python doc here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html#doctest.testfile):

> Optional argument `raise_on_error` defaults to false. If true, an
>   exception is raised upon the first failure or unexpected exception in
>   an example. This allows failures to be post-mortem debugged. Default
>   behavior is to continue running examples.

Comment: Unfortunately using `raise_on_error` leads to a missing test output, so I switched to `sys.exit` based solution.

Comment: @geekQ I'm using `verbose` flag in combination with `raise_on_error`  to produce output and this allows to figure out which test has failed: `doctest.testmod(verbose=True, raise_on_error=True)`

Answer (score 7):

@fossilet's answer works for properly breaking builds that fail tests, but it raises the exception before doctest is able to write anything to the console. This makes your logs much less useful for identifying the problem.

An alternative is to call

```
sys.exit(doctest.testmod()[0])
```

This makes the process exit code equal to the number of tests that failed. Your CI tool should interpret nonzero exit codes as failing builds. But the doctest output will still make it to the console.